# Connecting to app server using plink

Tags: ssh, putty, cmd.exe, plink

I need to connect to psadmin using plink.

Try: `plink -ssh [hostname] -l [user] -pw [password] psadmin`

When I run this I get error code 127 Command not found: psadmin

When I enter into the shell using plink and run psadmin. This works fine. Is this a issue with permissions? Or Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The remote shell might depend on configuration like /etc/profile to find the `psadmin` program; on Linux, some distributions don't enable the needed options when compiling bash. So tell it to read the configuration manually:

```
plink [user]@[hostname] ". /etc/profile && psadmin"
```

---

(Also, `-pw`? Really, make a key for use with `-i` instead.)

Comment: grawity, I tried it and got the following error
`plink -ssh [hostname] -l [username] -pw [password] ". /etc/profile && psadmin"`
ksh: line 1: psadmin: not found
Plink error: Command not found on remote host
(Exit code 127)